# Validating Blazor Server DynamicComponent

Tags: c#, .net, validation, blazor, blazor-editform

How would I go about validating 1 to many DynamicComponents in Blazor. For instance, I have a razor component that has two DateTime pickers

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <TelerikDateTimePicker @bind-Value="@selectedStartDate"
                           Id="selected-start-date" OnChange="@timeChange"> 
    </TelerikDateTimePicker>
</div>            
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <TelerikDateTimePicker @bind-Value="@selectedEndDate"
                           Id="selected-end-date" OnChange="@timeChange"> 
   </TelerikDateTimePicker>
</div>
```

I also have a similar DynamicComponent that simply has a start datetime with a range, and the user may choose a combination of these components. So far, I'm able to retrieve the values from the child component into the parent. I'm just confused as to how to go about validating these separate dynamic components. Should I encompass everything in an `<EditForm>` tag, in which case do I use a Model or EditContext?

```
<CascadingValue Value="appstate">
    @foreach(string ActionID in SelectedActionIDs)
    {
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <DynamicComponent Type="@components[ActionID].Type" 
                              Parameters="@components[ActionID].Parameters">
            </DynamicComponent>    
        </div>
    }
</CascadingValue>
```

Comment: Have you asked Telerik?  Most people that answer questions here aren't familiar with specific commercial supplier's components.